# Error generating log file in the win32 console project

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, ini

I have a code to generate a log file :-

```
// INI.cpp: implementation of the CINI class.


//#include "stdafx.h"

#include "INI.h"
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[]=__FILE__;
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


CINI::CINI(char* szFileName)
{

    memset(m_szFileName, 0x00, 255); 
    memcpy(m_szFileName, szFileName, strlen(szFileName));

}

CINI::~CINI()
{

}


float CINI::ReadFloat(char* szSection, char* szKey, float fltDefaultValue)
{
    char szResult[255]; 
    char szDefault[255]; 
    float fltResult; sprintf(szDefault, "%f",fltDefaultValue); 
    GetPrivateProfileString(szSection,  szKey, szDefault, szResult, 255, m_szFileName);  
    fltResult =  atof(szResult); return fltResult;
}

bool CINI::ReadBoolean(char* szSection, char* szKey, bool bolDefaultValue)
{
    char szResult[255]; 
    char szDefault[255]; 
    bool bolResult; 
    sprintf(szDefault, "%s", bolDefaultValue? "True" : "False"); 
    GetPrivateProfileString(szSection, szKey, szDefault, szResult, 255, m_szFileName);
    bolResult =  (strcmp(szResult, "True") == 0 || strcmp(szResult, "true") == 0) ? true : false; return bolResult;
}

char* CINI::ReadString(char* szSection, char* szKey, const char* szDefaultValue)
{ 
    memset(m_szResult, 0x00, 255); 
    GetPrivateProfileString(szSection,  szKey, szDefaultValue, m_szResult, 255, m_szFileName);  
    return m_szResult;
}

void CINI::WriteInteger(char* szSection, char* szKey, int iValue)
{ 
    char szValue[255]; sprintf(szValue, "%d", iValue); 
    WritePrivateProfileString(szSection,  szKey, szValue, m_szFileName);
}

void CINI::WriteFloat(char* szSection, char* szKey, float fltValue)
{
    char szValue[255]; 
    sprintf(szValue, "%f", fltValue); 
    WritePrivateProfileString(szSection,  szKey, szValue, m_szFileName);
}

void CINI::WriteBoolean(char* szSection, char* szKey, bool bolValue)
{ 
    char szValue[255]; sprintf(szValue, "%s", bolValue ? "True" : "False"); 
    WritePrivateProfileString(szSection,  szKey, szValue, m_szFileName);
}

void CINI::WriteString(char* szSection, char* szKey, char* szValue)
{
    WritePrivateProfileString(szSection,  szKey, szValue, m_szFileName);
}
```

**I am getting the following errors when I run the code:-**

```
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(24): fatal error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]
```

**When I include the StdAfx.h and StdAfx.cpp i get the following errors:-**

```
 StdAfx.cpp
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(24): fatal error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]
1>  INI.cpp
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(24): fatal error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]
```

I am using VS2010 and need to build win32 console project. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your project's properties:

Go to the Project-> Properties (the last menu item) -> Configuration Properties -> General.

There you'll see the "Project Defaults" section with the "Use of MFC" option. Choose the "Use MFC in a static library".

Basically, you're getting the conflict, because in the code generation settings the multi-threaded static run-time library is chosen and the MFC library that you're trying to use is built using the dll-based C run-time.

Comment: Sir the above solution u mentioned is in which case including  StdAfx.h and StdAfx.cpp in the project or not,if the case is not including the  StdAfx.h and StdAfx.cpp  and selecting Runtime Libraray in code generation as /MT i am getting the following errors LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __initp_misc_invarg already defined in libcmtd.lib(invarg.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __call_reportfault already defined in libcmtd.lib(invarg.obj)